# Docked control tabs not rendering correclty

Tags: wpf, tabs

I'm working on customizing a user control containing a tab control child element. The user control docks to the side of the main window. I want the tab items to orient based on the docking position, eg. left docked tab items rotate 90 degrees to lay along the side. I have the tabs aligning correctly by binding to the attached property DockPanel.Dock. The problem is that when the tabs are rendered they are disconnected by a line from the tab control. I can manually set the (DockPanel.Dock) property for the outer user control object and the tabs docked along that direction draw correctly but the other tabs are separated by a line.

Here is the TabDockControl XML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="AnimationMotionCaptureStudio.TabDockControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" x:Name="Root" DockPanel.Dock="Left">
<Grid>
    <TabControl Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="tabControl1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" TabStripPlacement="{Binding Path=(DockPanel.Dock),ElementName=Root}">
        <TabControl.Resources>

            <Style TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
                <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </Setter.Value>
                </Setter>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding Path=(DockPanel.Dock), ElementName=Root}" Value="Left">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2" />
                        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                                        <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="90" />
                                        </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                    </ContentPresenter>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                    <DataTrigger  Binding="{Binding Path=(DockPanel.Dock), ElementName=Root}" Value="Right">
                        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="5" />
                        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
                            <Setter.Value>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding Content}">
                                        <ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                            <RotateTransform Angle="-90" />
                                        </ContentPresenter.LayoutTransform>
                                    </ContentPresenter>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </Setter.Value>
                        </Setter>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TabControl.Resources>

        <TabItem Header="{Binding Path=(DockPanel.Dock), ElementName=Root}" Name="tabItem1">
            <Grid>
                <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="1" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="border1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" />
            </Grid>
        </TabItem>
    </TabControl>
</Grid>
```

The code behind file has no additional code added beyond the constructor generated by VS2010.

And the MainWindow XML usage of the control:

```
        <DockPanel Grid.Row="1" Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="MainDockPanel" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" >
        <DockPanel.Children>
            <StatusBar Height="23" Name="statusBar1" Width="Auto" DockPanel.Dock="Bottom" Background="#FF00476D" />

            <AMCS:TabDockControl DockPanel.Dock="Left">
            </AMCS:TabDockControl>

            <AMCS:TabDockControl DockPanel.Dock="Right">
            </AMCS:TabDockControl>              

            <AMCS:TabDockControl DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
            </AMCS:TabDockControl>
            <Border BorderBrush="Silver" BorderThickness="2" Height="Auto" Name="border1" Width="Auto" DockPanel.Dock="Top" Background="#FF898888">
                <Image Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Name="D3DImage" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="Auto" MouseLeftButtonDown="D3DImage_MouseLeftButtonDown" MouseLeftButtonUp="D3DImage_MouseLeftButtonUp" MouseMove="D3DImage_MouseMove" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Row="1" MouseWheel="D3DImage_MouseWheel">
                    <Image.Source>
                        <i:D3DImage x:Name="D3DImageSource"/>
                    </Image.Source>
                </Image>
            </Border>
        </DockPanel.Children>
    </DockPanel>
```

Any suggestions for how to set this up to render the tabs correctly would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post of a screenshot of what line you are talking about? When I run your code I see this: http://tinypic.com/r/r8gxmg/5

Comment: It says I have to have ten points to be able to post picture. That is exactly what I'm wanting, what you got. In the Editor it works fine but when I run the application the right tab has a line separating it from the tabcontrol. Like it was a label laying on top and to the right of the tabcontrol. The same happens to the bottom tab. The Left tab looks correct though.  Hers is a link to a picture of the tabs. [link]http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=2n0lnxl&s=5#.UmGnC50o7RY

Comment: I finally realized what dumb thing I was doing. I didn't set the center of rotation for the Layout Transform. Thank you for your help.